# Representations and the Notion of Equivalecne

Tags: matrices, representation-theory

I started studying representations of groups and am trying to confirm my understanding of one particular aspect.  If $(\rho, V)$ is a representation of a group you can either think of $\rho(g_i)$ where $g_i\in G$ as a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ or if you pick a basis you can think of it as an invertible matrix, say $M$ for one basis and $N$ for another.  Now, picking a basis doesn't change $T$ but you can often pick more than one basis for $T$.  Let $F$ be a field.  Since the ring $F[G]$ over itself is a free module whose basis elements are comprised of the set $\{g_i\}$ the basis would have $|G|$ elements.  However, the faithful representations when expressed as a matrix often do not have order an $|G|$ basis.  This is explained by the fact two matrices representing the same $T$ are similar.  I.e., assume $\rho(g_1)=M$ and $\rho(g_2)=N$ where $M$ and $N$ are the same transformation but in a different basis and let $h\in G$ then
$$
PMP^{-1}\cong N\implies \rho(h)\rho(g_1)\rho(h)^{-1}\cong \rho(g_2)\implies hg_1h^{-1}=g_2
$$ hence when representing a group we can think of elements of the same conjugacy class as, in a sense, the same transformation but in a different basis.  So, I guess my question is, in what sense?  Is it fair to say that elements of the same conjugacy class correspond to the same dimension of the transformation?  That last sentence doesn't really make sense I know but that's the part I'm trying to make clear.

EDIT: (This particular edit is nonsense, ignore it.  The next edit is the correct idea):  Maybe I answered my own question.  Does thinking about a  representation in terms of a linear transformation capture the idea of a torsor?  For example, take the conjugacy class corresponding to rotations of $S_n$ for some $n$.  Then a rotation without a basis is meaningless but you can measure the difference between two rotations.  That is analagous to the common example of a torsor, i.e., a vector space without an origin.

EDIT:  After further study I found out that the notion on the tip of my brain I was trying to make clear has already been made precise.  Basically, I was trying to grasp the idea of class functions and the fact that they form a vector space.  It has to do with the characters of a representation.